# listview item text allignment

Tags: android, text, listviewitem

I have a list layout with 9patch .png used for each item - I have a small text allignment issue as in the attached pic.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Here is the first entry layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/list_up" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listUp_RecipeIngredientNameTextBoxId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the 2nd entry layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/list_middle" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listMiddle_RecipeIngredientNameTextBoxId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the layout? Do you want to center the text vertically?

Comment: I want to allign the text inside the list item... left allignment as in the first entry Check out my edit

Answer (score 0):

Assuming list_middle and list_up are 9patch drawables, the difference should be in the "padding" specified in the 9patch images. You can solve this making both 9patch have the same amount of pixels in the borders (ie the width of the "left" part of the 9patch and the height of the "top" part of the 9patch).

Comment: Can I do it inside the 9Patch tool?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Look at the black lines, these lines divide the image.